# Is IHostedService.StopAsync waiting for request threads?

Tags: asp.net-core

When stopping a `ASP.NET Core` server with instances of  `IHostedService`s, can calls to `StopAsync` enter meanwhile a request thread is still being processed? Or will calls to StopAsync automatically wait until all active request threads are done? And will new requests be stopped once StopAsync is in progress?

I'm not sure this is specific to `IHostedService`. Maybe the question is weather `ASP.NET Core` in general will wait for requests to finish before continuing with shutdown, if the shutdown is initiated during processing of requests? And if this in turn is also causing `StopAsync` on instances of `IHostedService` to be postposed until requests are done.

And if `ASP.NET Core` in general will stop new requests once shutdown is commenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosted services run outside of requests, so they really shouldn’t care about whether or not there are requests ongoing.

That being said, hosted services are started *after* the web application has been built and started, but are stopped *after* the web application has been shut down. This is the releavant part of [the source](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/2.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/WebHost.cs#L324-L336) for that:

```
// Fire IApplicationLifetime.Stopping
_applicationLifetime?.StopApplication();

if (Server != null)
{
    await Server.StopAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// Fire the IHostedService.Stop
if (_hostedServiceExecutor != null)
{
    await _hostedServiceExecutor.StopAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Since the Kestrel server will usually attempt to shut down its connections gracefully, you can expect all requests to be terminated by the time the `StopAsync` of your `IHostedService` runs.